# Which beamer theme is this? Or how to create the one like this

Tags: beamer

Could anyone please help, which beamer theme is this? Or how to create one like this? Any help will really be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Look through [the beamer theme matrix](http://www.hartwork.org/beamer-theme-matrix/) for other examples. This one is similar to the Palo Alto theme.

Comment: If you find you can't adapt that theme appropriately, post back with the code you've got and explain what specific step you are stuck on. Remember to make sure that you post a complete small document (Minimal Working Example) which people can compile to help you.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It is not one of the default themes, but you can create it:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme[shadow=false]{rounded}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\useoutertheme{sidebar}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{94,124,114}% green-gray
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{192,0,0}% red

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{bg=color2,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=color1,fg=red}

%\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{bg=color2,fg=color2}
%\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{bg=color1,fg=color2}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=color2,fg=white}
\setbeamercolor{logo}{bg=color1,fg=white}

\setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{fg=white,bg=color1}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
      \else%
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate (aux)
  at (\beamer@leftsidebar,-0.2\paperheight);
\coordinate (aux2)
  at (\beamer@leftsidebar,0);
\draw[
  line width=4pt,
  color2,
  rounded corners
  ]
  (\beamer@leftsidebar,0|-aux) --
  (aux2) --
  (\paperwidth,0|-aux2);
\node[
  outer sep=0pt,
  draw=color2,
  anchor=south,
  fill=white,
  text=black,
  circle,minimum size=14pt
  ] (numbu)
  at (aux) 
    {\insertsectionnumber};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
  \includegraphics[]{back}%
}

\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar left}{}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\coordinate (aux)
  at (\beamer@leftsidebar,.65\paperheight);
\draw[
  line width=4pt,
  black
  ]
  (\beamer@leftsidebar,0) -- 
  (\beamer@leftsidebar,0|-aux);
\node[
  outer sep=0pt,
  draw=black,
  anchor=south,
  fill=white,
  text=black,
  circle,minimum size=14pt
  ] (numbl)
  at (\beamer@leftsidebar,0) 
    {\insertframenumber};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother    

\logo{Logo}
\title[The title for the sidebar]{The title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Test section one}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Test section two}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame}
test
\end{frame}

\section{Test section three}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result, showing the title frame and an inner frame:

[image]

Some meaning of some elements in the image was not clear; in particular, the meaning of the numbers inside the circles next to the sidebar was not clearly specified in the question, so I used the section number and the frame number; those elements can be appropriately modified to give the desired result.

The image `back.png` I used for the `background` template is just a fragment from the original background:

[image]

Comment: Very good. This deserves more upvotes. :)

Comment: Wow, theme reverse engineering!